# Find previous merge commit in release branch

Tags: git, github, github-api

At work we have a dev branch and a release branch. Once in a while we merge dev into release: to do so we create a Pull Request on github and then we merge it.

I am making an integration tool to tell us various things, for example who are the authors of the commits in between 2 releases. **I would like to find the sha of the previous dev->release merge**.

I manage to use **github's API** to some extent:

- I automatically retrieved the pull request number from the last dev -> release
- I know how to get all the info from commits between any 2 commits if I know their sha
- **All I need now** is a good way to find when was the previous dev -> release merge: I manage to iterate/page through all the last commits and can see in the debug logs the previous dev->release merge (I looked up its sha manually), so I know it is there, but I don't know how I can automatically tell to stop apart from maybe checking the commit message but it feels a bit dirty and not always accurate.

Please note that this is some internal tooling and I cannot use git command line tools. I looked up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525695/how-to-find-previous-merge-commit) too

Answer (score 0):

GitHub doesn't provide this functionality in the API. You want to use a command-line invocation that provides an answer as in the question you linked to, or write a (quite complex) invocation using libgit2 or a wrapper around it. That is the only way to get a correct response for this.

If you are absolutely, 100% certain that people are only going to use the standard Git command-line tools, you can use [this API call](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository) to walk the history and look for an appropriate commit message indicating a merge. However, if anyone ever edits the commit message or uses another tool, then you will miss entries.

You could also walk the history via the GitHub API to find all merges in the `release` branch and find the first commit that matches the second parent that's in the `dev` branch, but this is inefficient and will likely result in you getting rate-limited.

Comment: Thanks! So finally I see that when I merge to release, the commit message has the pull request's number, and I can use the pull request api to list all commits related to that PR. It looks like the previous deploy is the commit in the history just before the first commit in the PR, so I'm looking at this right now

Answer (score 0):

You could create a tag whenever a release is made, using a version number. This way it can be easier, knowing two releases you want to compare, to work on them (e.g. `git log tag1..tag2`, or equivalent).

Finding the previous release would pretty much be current version number - 1.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I think we are still trying to figure out what is the best way for our deployment process